# Using nls or nlsLM to fit global and group-specific parameters

Tags: r, parameters, grouping, nls

I would like to use nls to fit a global parameter and group-specific parameters. The closest I have found to a minimum reproducible example is below (found here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-September/432020.html)

```
#Generate some data
d <- transform(data.frame(x=seq(0,1,len=17),
     group=rep(c("A","B","B","C"),len=17)), y =
     round(1/(1.4+x^ifelse(group=="A", 2.3, ifelse(group=="B",3.1, 3.5))),2))

#Fit to model using nls
nls(y~1/(b+x^p[group]), data=d, start=list(b=1, p=rep(3,length(levels(d$group)))))
```

This gives me an error:

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env, central = nDcentral) :
> Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I have not been able to figure out if the error is coming from bad guesses for the starting values, or the way this code is dealing with group-specific parameters. It seems the line with `p=rep(3,length(levels(d$group)))` is for generating `c(3,3,3)`, but switching this part of the code does not remove the problem (same error obtained as above):

```
#Fit to model using nls
nls(y~1/(b+x^p[group]), data=d, start=list(b=1, p=c(3, 3, 3)))
```

Switching to nlsLM gives a different error which leads be to believe I am having an issue with the group-specific parameters:

```
#Generate some data
library(minpack.lm)
d <- transform(data.frame(x=seq(0,1,len=17),
                          group=rep(c("A","B","B","C"),len=17)), y =
                 round(1/(1.4+x^ifelse(group=="A", 2.3, ifelse(group=="B",3.1, 3.5))),2))

#Fit to model using nlsLM
nlsLM(y~1/(b+x^p[group]), data=d, start=list(b=1, p=c(3,3,3)))
```

Error:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this by switching the class of the group from chr to factor. Note the addition of `factor()` when generating the dataset.

```
> d <- transform(data.frame(
+       x=seq(0,1,len=17),
+       group=rep(factor(c("A","B","B","C")),len=17)),
+       y=round(1/(1.4+x^ifelse(group=="A", 2.3, ifelse(group=="B",3.1, 3.5))),2)
+     )
> str(d)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x    : num  0 0.0625 0.125 0.1875 0.25 ...
 $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 2 ...
 $ y    : num  0.71 0.71 0.71 0.71 0.69 0.7 0.69 0.69 0.62 0.64 ...
> nls(y~1/(b+x^p[group]), data=d, start=list(b=1, p=c(3,3,3)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1/(b + x^p[group])
   data: d
    b    p1    p2    p3 
1.406 2.276 3.186 3.601 
 residual sum-of-squares: 9.537e-05

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.536e-06
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this much more easily with `nlme::gnls`:

```r
fit2 <- nlme::gnls(y~1/(b+x^p),
           params = list(p~group-1, b~1), 
           data=d, 
           start = list(b=1, p = rep(3,3)))
```

Results:

```
Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
  Model: y ~ 1/(b + x^p) 
  Data: d 
  Log-likelihood: 62.05887

Coefficients:
p.groupA p.groupB p.groupC        b 
2.262383 2.895903 3.475324 1.407561 

Degrees of freedom: 17 total; 13 residual
Residual standard error: 0.007188101
```

The `params` argument allows you to specify fixed-effect submodels for each nonlinear parameter. Using `p ~ b-1` parameterizes the model with a separate estimate for each group, rather than fitting a baseline (intercept) value for the first group and the differences between successive groups. (In R's formula language, `-1` or `+0` signify "fit a model without intercept/set the intercept to 0", which in this case corresponds to fitting all three groups separately.)

I'm quite surprised that `gnls` and `nls` *don't* give identical results (although both give reasonable results); would like to dig in further ...

[image: points and fitted curves for nls and gnls]

Parameter estimates (code below):

```
  term    nls  gnls
1 b      1.41  1.40
2 pA     2.28  2.28
3 pB     3.19  3.14
4 pC     3.60  3.51
```

---

```r
par(las = 1, bty = "l")
plot(y~x, data = d, col = d$group, pch = 16)
xvec <- seq(0, 1, length = 21)
f <- function(x) factor(x, levels = c("A","B","C"))
## fit1 is nls() fit
ll <- function(g, c = 1) {
  lines(xvec, predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(group=f(g), x = xvec)), col = c)
}
Map(ll, LETTERS[1:3], 1:3)
d2 <- expand.grid(x = xvec, group = f(c("A","B","C")))
pp <- predict(fit2, newdata = d2)
ll2 <- function(g, c = 1) {
  lines(xvec, pp[d2$group == g], lty = 2, col = c)
}
Map(ll2, LETTERS[1:3], 1:3)
legend("bottomleft", lty = 1:2, col = 1, legend = c("nls", "gnls"))

library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)
(purrr::map_dfr(list(nls=fit1, gnls=fit2), tidy, .id = "pkg")
  %>% select(pkg, term, estimate)
  %>% group_by(pkg)
  ## force common parameter names
  %>% mutate(across(term, ~ c("b", paste0("p", LETTERS[1:3]))))
  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = pkg, values_from = estimate)
)
```

Comment: I was able to successfully fit my actual data (a more complex function) using this approach and obtained physically meaningless values for the group-specific parameters, here p.(Intercept), p.groupB, and p.groupC. If you compare the obtained group-specific p coefficients to the ones posted in the link above, you'll see they are quite different. After reading the nlme manual I think this is because each group is simultaneously fit to p.(intercept), p(groupB), and p(groupC), when they should only be allowed to fit to their group-specific p coefficient. Thanks for the new direction, anyway!

Comment: Can you point me to the place in the manual you're referring to?

Comment: Just the package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf I may be wrong about the sharing of group-specific parameters in the case of gnls, but it's the conclusion I came to after looking at my own data. In that set, the differences for the groups-specific parameters are glaringly different between nls and gnls (i.e. negative values for gnls and positive for nls).

Comment: Parameter estimates aren't glaringly different (at least in the test example) once you use `p ~ group-1` rather than `p ~ group` in the `params` argument .... ?

Comment: Yes, the same for my dataset: ```p~group-1``` in gnls gives almost identical result to the nls parameters. This also results in pgroupA instead of p.(intercept) in this test case. Do you mind explaining the significance of the -1 term in ```p~group-1```?

Comment: From my answer: "Using p ~ b-1 parameterizes the model with a separate estimate for each group, rather than fitting a baseline (intercept) value for the first group and the differences between successive groups."